# Problem with processing .CR2 format in Linux

Tags: canon, raw, linux, rawtherapee

first time I used Canon and all my programs -Rawtherapee, Darktable, UFRaw, Rawstudio - opened the photos as below. Anyone has idea why this is happening and how to fix it? I use Linux and I'm used to working in Rawtherapee so I'd prefer to make that one work.

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Lucie

Comment: What particular Canon camera? What version of each program you have listed?

Comment: Canon Powershot G16, rawtherapee-4.0.11-1.fc19.x86_64, ufraw-0.19.2-10.fc19.x86_64, darktable-1.2.2-1.fc19.x86_64, rawstudio-2.0-11.fc19.x86_64
too old? is it the problem?

Answer (score 4):

RawTherapee supports Canon PowerShot G16 starting RawTherapee version 4.2.

Answer (score 4):

That is the result of the raw processing program not having the correct profile for the said camera. Getting an updated version should resolve your problem. The list of cameras supported by RawTherapee, together with the version number since, can be found at RawPedia.

Answer (score 0):

Results like that You can have if to use non-full *CR2. Canon camera (some) can to have three parameters of raw file, for example: cr2 (18 Mpix), cr2 (10 Mpix), cr2 (5 Mpix). And if You use second cr2 (or third) - Rawtherapee can`t understand it, but to use first - all be OK.